# sheaf of hyperplanes

Tags: terminology

I've got a question on terminology.

In 3d, a set of planes intersecting at a point is called a bundle of planes.
A set of planes intersecting along a line is called a sheaf of planes.

My question concerns hyperplanes in 4d. What is the relevant terminology there?

I presume I can still refer to hyperplanes intersecting at a point as a bundle of hyperplanes. However, hyperplanes can also intersect along a line or along a 2d plane. What should I call those?

Comment: Where is this terminology used? I don't recall having seen it before.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SheafofPlanes.html